# csv to wav python

Tags: python, csv, wav

Hi i have this code that suppose to convert csv file to wav file.
it creates a wav file but we don't hear anything. If i put 10 rows in the csv file, it make an about 1 min wav file ! So it is not proportional at all.

my csv looks like:

```
0.000785,0.30886552
0.00157,0.587527526
0.002355,0.808736061
0.00314,0.950859461
0.003925,0.999999683
0.00471,0.951351376
0.005495,0.809671788
0.00628,0.588815562
0.007065,0.31037991
0.00785,0.001592653
0.008635,-0.307350347
0.00942,-0.586237999
0.010205,-0.807798281
0.01099,-0.950365133
0.011775,-0.999997146
0.01256,-0.951840879
0.013345,-0.810605462
0.01413,-0.590102105
0.014915,-0.311893512
0.0157,-0.003185302
0.016485,0.305834394
0.01727,0.584946986
0.018055,0.806858453
0.01884,0.949868395
0.019625,0.999992073
0.02041,0.952327967
0.021195,0.81153708
0.02198,0.591387151
0.022765,0.313406323
```

and the code here:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import wave
import numpy
import struct
import sys
import csv
import resampy

def write_wav(data, filename, framerate, amplitude):
    wavfile = wave.open(filename, "w")
    nchannels = 1
    sampwidth = 2
    framerate = framerate
    nframes = len(data)
    comptype = "NONE"
    compname = "not compressed"
    wavfile.setparams((nchannels,
                        sampwidth,
                        framerate,
                        nframes,
                        comptype,
                        compname))
    #print("Please be patient while the file is written")
    frames = []
    for s in data:
        mul = int(s * amplitude)
        # print "s: %f mul: %d" % (s, mul)
        frames.append(struct.pack('h', mul))
    #frames = (struct.pack('h', int(s*self.amp)) for s in sine_list)
    frames = ''.join(frames)
    #for x in xrange(0, 7200):
    wavfile.writeframes(frames)
    wavfile.close()
    print("%s written" %(filename))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) <= 1:
        print ("You must supply a filename to generate")
        exit(-1)
    for fname in sys.argv[1:]:

        data = []
        for time, value in csv.reader(open(fname, 'U'), delimiter=','):
            try:
                data.append(float(value))
            except ValueError:
                pass # Just skip it


        print("This is data lenght: %d" %(len(data)))
        arr = numpy.array(data)
        print arr
        # Normalize data
        arr /= numpy.max(numpy.abs(data))
        print arr
        filename_head, extension = fname.rsplit(".", 1)
        # Resample normalized data to 8000 kHz
        target_samplerate = 8000
        sampled = resampy.resample(arr, target_samplerate/100000.0,16000)
        #print sampled
        write_wav(sampled, "new" + ".wav", target_samplerate, 32700)
        print ("File written succesfully !")
```

The original code is from github - pretz with some fixes i saw on google.

thanks all

Comment: please format your code correctly

Answer (score 7):

RESOLVED ! Here the code for converting a CSV file in a WAV file.
The CSV file must have 2 columns: 
The first is the time of the sample - in this file it doesn't matter so you can put 0 to all this column.
The second column is the sample itself - for example if your sample is 16 bit length - the sample should be between -32678 and 32767 ( int range ). This number will be normalize between -1 and 1 in line 56.
After the have this file you just have to run the .py with the filename of the csv file as an argument. ( like python generate.py sinewave.csv ).

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import wave
import struct
import sys
import csv
import numpy 
from scipy.io import wavfile
from scipy.signal import resample

def write_wav(data, filename, framerate, amplitude):
    wavfile = wave.open(filename,'w')
    nchannels = 1
    sampwidth = 2
    framerate = framerate
    nframes = len(data)
    comptype = "NONE"
    compname = "not compressed"
    wavfile.setparams((nchannels,
                        sampwidth,
                        framerate,
                        nframes,
                        comptype,
                        compname))
    frames = []
    for s in data:
        mul = int(s * amplitude)
        frames.append(struct.pack('h', mul))

    frames = ''.join(frames)
    wavfile.writeframes(frames)
    wavfile.close()
    print("%s written" %(filename)) 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) <= 1:
        print ("You must supply a filename to generate")
        exit(-1)
    for fname in sys.argv[1:]:

        data = []
        for time, value in csv.reader(open(fname, 'U'), delimiter=','):
            try:
                data.append(float(value))#Here you can see that the time column is skipped
            except ValueError:
                pass # Just skip it


        arr = numpy.array(data)#Just organize all your samples into an array
        # Normalize data
        arr /= numpy.max(numpy.abs(data)) #Divide all your samples by the max sample value
        filename_head, extension = fname.rsplit(".", 1)        
        data_resampled = resample( arr, len(data) )
        wavfile.write('rec.wav', 16000, data_resampled) #resampling at 16khz
        print ("File written succesfully !")
```

Enjoy !

```
CSV example:
0 , 20
0 , 15
0 , -40
0 , -1000
...
```

Comment: Then where do you use the `write_wav` function in the main ?

Comment: i don't. it's a mistake.it is not a good code, i improved it since.

Comment: Then remove that part of code that you're not using. It's confusing. Also if this solved the problem, then mark it  as 'accepted answer'. Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Use [pysoundfile](https://pysoundfile.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#soundfile.write)

```
import pandas as pd
import soundfile as sf

# assume we have columns 'time' and 'value'
df = pd.read_csv('recording.csv')

# compute sample rate, assuming times are in seconds
times = df['time'].values
n_measurements = len(times)
timespan_seconds = times[-1] - times[0]
sample_rate_hz = int(n_measurements / timespan_seconds)

# write data
data = df['value'].values
sf.write('recording.wav', data, sample_rate_hz)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks khornlund, your code helped. I also had to normalize the data though for proper playback:

```
import numpy as np
from playsound import playsound

data_n = data
data_n = data_n / np.max(np.abs(data_n))
sf.write('recording.wav', data_n, sample_rate_hz)
playsound('recording.wav')
status = sd.wait()  # Wait until file is done playing
```