# Convert from pressure data to a sound

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, interpolation, linear-interpolation

I'm using a pressure sensor to "record" a sound coming from a stethoscope. As a result i have a file containing the pressure values. Plotting the results with this simple python code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

x = []
y = []

with open('dati1.csv','r') as csvfile:
    plots = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in plots:
        x.append(float(row[0]))
        y.append(float(row[1]))

plt.plot(x,y, label='Dati provenienti dallo stetoscopio')
plt.xlabel('tempo')
plt.ylabel('pressione')
plt.title('Grafico battito cardiaco')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

here's what i see:
[plot of the wave](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IH3XV.png).
I'd like to convert the values of pressure to a file audio. I tried to use the code that can be found in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41209733/csv-to-wav-python), but the result is a really short noise. I looked for a way to enhance my data which are sampled around 100 Hz, due to the fact that my sensor can't go faster than that, using interpolation. I'm not really skilled with python so I didn't managed to achive my goal. May u help me?

Comment: If you have the whole science stack, look at `import scipy.io.wavfile` and pandas `.resample`, those will get you there with a couple of one liners.

Comment: I managed to add values between my samples using linear interpolation, but when i convert them to wave file the result is a silent file audio. What am i missing?

Comment: you will have to update your question with your latest code, and also include a portion of the data that you have (say 1sec of your 100Hz data) so that your specific problem is repeatable. It's quite a hard task guessing what is going on without the details.

Comment: yes @ahed87 has great advice ... to render your data you may want to duplicate your set of points many times just assure the beginning and ending points on the stethoscope input data are about the same otherwise you will hear a loud pop sound due to a discontinuity in the curve shape as the ending point wraps to join with starting point ... a tool called Audacity lets you visualize the audio file to see this curve ... I would avoid doing any interpolation until after simply duplicating the set of points you have a many times  ... we await your updates

Comment: Unless your sounds are highly constrained, you have no prayer of getting meaningful data out of 100&nbsp;Hz of bandwidth—even POTS is [at least 8&nbsp;kHz](https://www.pcmech.com/article/why-does-voip-sound-so-much-better-than-pots/).

Comment: I feel like a dumb. It works but the volume was very low. Thank you guys for the help